# Different between Machine code and Processor code

Tags: machine-code

What's the different between  the Machine code and  the Processor code when we execute a computer by an Operating System.

Comment: I've not heard of "processor code". Do you have a reference link for this?

Answer (score 3):

Machine level code ususually looks

```
 8020   78
8021    A9 80
8023    8D 15 03
8026    A9 2D
8028    8D 14 03
802B    58
802C    60
802D    EE 20 D0
8030    4C 31 EA
```

where assembly looks like

```
Start:  .org $8020
SEI
LDA #$80
STA $0315
LDA #$2D
STA $0314
CLI
RTS
INC $D020
JMP $EA31
```

Assembly is "more readable" believe it or not. Also note they represent the same thing. Where you would program and read assembly, while machine is what computers would use. It is most times the processor that computes code.